# Override pause-on-hover behavior of Bootstrap 4 Carousel

Tags: hover, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm making a non-interactive carousel in Bootstrap 4. By default the carousel stays on the current slide while the user is hovering. How can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [Bootstrap 4.1.x official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/) for the carousel component.

You can use the attribute `data-pause="false"` when declaring your carousel, for example:

```
<div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-pause="false">
```

Comment: This is a really good answer because I looked at the current documentation and tried it and it didn't work:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/#options

Meaning, I tried passing options with JavaScript and it didn't work:

$('#carouselServiceBanner').carousel({
  pause: false
});

And I did not see your solution in the current documentation, but alas, it works.

Thank you!